# Как достать информацию из Git о изменении метаданных за определённый период времени с помощью GitPython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git

Нужно вытащить из проекта в гит(имеется лок копия) информацию об изменениях метаданных, а именно:
Кол-во коммитов по файлу(коду, методе) за 2 недели на определенной ветке

```
import os
import time
import git
import datetime
Changedata = {}
MY_PATH = os.chdir(r'C:\Users\vsi\int\sfdevops_metrics\.project\na_gold')
repo = git.Repo(MY_PATH)
commits = list(repo.iter_commits("Staging", datetime=))
```

Из кода только инициализация репы и задатки сортировки времени

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данная строка выводит нужную инфу

```
file = repo.git.log('--since=2.weeks', '--name-only')
```

Тобишь код выглядит так

```
import git
import re
import collections

j = collections.defaultdict(int)
Changedata = {}
#MY_PATH = '/home/bot_slack_git/na_gold/'
MY_PATH1 = r'C:\Users\vsi\int\sfdevops_metrics\.project\na_gold\force-app\main\default'
MY_PATH = r'C:\Users\vsi\int\na_gold'
repo = git.Repo(MY_PATH)
file = repo.git.log('--since=2.weeks', '--name-only')
```